# build a .txt file parsing html tags

Tags: powershell

I have strings inside `<h1>`string text`</h1>` inside a list of http links

I try to extract string text inside this specific HTML tag from URL list to export parsed content into a text *.txt* file

```
 # extract utils data and clean 
    $listbook = gci $rootpath -File | foreach {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            file = $_.FullName;
            books = ((iwr "https://www.site.zone/page/2/", "https://www.site.zone/page/3/").ParsedHtml.body.outerText

    # extract tag
    $myarray = gc $newpath |
               % { [regex]::Matches($_, '(?<=<h1>\s+)(.*?)(?=\s+</h1>)') } |
               select -expa value

    # build file text
    $listbook | %{
        $newpath = "$rootpathresult\$($_.subject)";
        New-Item -Path . -Name "testfile1.txt" -ItemType "file";
```

Comment: You're looking for the HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't use regexes to parse HTML; if you can use `.ParsedHtml`, you already have access to the DOM - no need to parse _text_.